# Unable to update extra attribute in join table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an attribute :row_order in a join table (which also has its own model: TodolistsTodo) and I'm trying to update it from another controller (Todos). How can I get at this attribute?

**Models**

```
class Todolist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos, through: :todolists_todos
  has_many :todolists_todos
end

class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RankedModel
  ranks :row_order
  has_many :todolists, through: :todolists_todos
  has_many :todolists_todos
end

class TodolistsTodo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todolists
  belongs_to :todo
end
```

**TodosController**

```
def update_row_order
    @todo = @parent.todos.find(todo_params[:todo_id])
    @todo.todolists_todo.where(:todolist_id => @parent.id).update_attribute :row_order,     todo_params[:todolists_attributes][:row_order]
    @todo.save

    render nothing: true
  end

private

    def todo_params
      params.require(:todo).permit(:todo_id, :todotype, :description, :status, :help, todolists_attributes: [:id, :row_order, :todolist_id, :todo_id])
    end
```

The update_attribute line understandably fails, because the where results in a CollectionProxy and the update_attribute method can only handle a single result. However, I also don't want to update_all.

**Ajax call to controller**

```
  todo_url = '/todolists/' + todolist_id + '/todos/update_row_order'
    $.ajax(
      type: 'POST'
      url: todo_url
      dataType: 'json'
      data: { todo: {todo_id: item_id, todolists_attributes: { row_order: position } } }
    )
```

Comment: What are you trying to update? :row_order seems to be an attribute of `Todo`, not of `TodolistsTodo`. Why is everything so complicated? Don't you have the id of the todo you want to update?

Comment: In my todolists_todos table in the PostgreSQL db it has a row_order column, alongside the todolist_id and todo_id columns. I have the id of the todo I want to update, but it doesn't have row_order because the row_order will be different for each todolist the todo is a part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that your `TodolistsTodo` has the `:row_oder`, and knowing, there can be only one `TodolistTodo` for each Todolist and ToDo, assuming that @parent is the todolist, use

```
@parent = Todolist.find params[:todolist_id]
@item = @parent.todolists_todo.where(todo_id: params[:todo][:todo_id]).first
@item.update_attribute :row_order, todo_params[:todolists_attributes][:row_order]
```

Comment: I see, so we're making sure update_attribute only works on one result by taking the first relation since there can be only one anyway. All I had to do then was add a primary key to the model (the join table was originally a has_and_belongs_to_many without a model before I added row_order).